# How do I redirect some requests to another domain?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I set up a site and changed the old site's name. So temporarily 2 sites are running.

- www.mydomain.com (new site)
- legacy.mydomain.com (old site)

The problem is that still some traffic comes to the new site mistakenly and I don't want my rails application to handle that (rails is kinda slow and takes lotta resources).
Instead, I want apache to redirect it to the old one before it reaches to the rails app.

The wrong traffic url is always like "www.mydomain.com/bbs/...". So I want to filter out requests with '/bbs/' and redirect it to "legacy.mydomain.com/bbs/...". I think I can do that on my .htaccess file. But I don't know how to write the rule. mod_rewrite is installed on my server.

Can you help?
Thanks.

Sam

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain\.com$   [NC]
RewriteRule ^bbs/ http://legacy.mydomain.com%{REQUEST_URI}  [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hmmm, it didn't work. So I used routes.rb to redirect. Thanks.